# Use the Division Algorithm to show the square of any integer is in the form $3k$ or $3k+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Use Division Algorithm to show the square of any int is in the form 3k or 3k+1

What confuses me about this is that I think I am able to show that the square of any integer is in the form $X*k$ where $x$ is any integer. For Example:

$$x = 3q + 0 \\
x = 3q + 1 \\
x = 3q + 2$$

I show $3k$ first
$$(3q)^2 = 3(3q^2)$$
where $k=3q^2$ is this valid use of the division algorithm?

If it is then can I also say that int is in the form for example 10*k

for example

$(3q)^2 = 10*(\frac{9}{10}q^2)$

where $k=(\frac{9}{10}q^2)$

Why isn't this valid? Am I using the div algorithm incorrectly to show that any integer is the form 3k and 3k+1, if so how do I use it? Keep in mind I am teaching myself Number Theory and the only help I can get is from you guys in stackexchange.

Comment: How do you know that $\frac 9 {10}q^2$ is an integer?

Comment: Good point I guess that is the reason that is 10k is invalid. The form $(3q+2)^2$ is not in the form 3k or 3k+1 without getting a fraction, how to account for that to finish the problem?

Comment: If $x = 10k$ then you should also consider all the other cases of $x = 10k + 1, 10k+2, \ldots + 10k+9.$ I don't see why you want to consider that.

Comment: $(3q+2)^2$ is not in the form $3k$ or $3k+1$ *seemingly.* Start expanding the square $(3q+2)^2 = (3q+2)(3q+2) = (3q)^2 + (2)^2 + 2(3q)(2) = ?????$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the division algorithm, $$x = 3q + r,\text{ where } r \in \{0, 1, 2\}.$$ So express $$x^2 = 9q^2 + r^2 + 6qr = 3(3q^2  + 2qr) + r^2.$$ For a given $x$ if $r = 0$ or $1,$ then we're done. If $r = 2$ then $r^2 = 4  = 3 + 1,$ and hence $$x^2 = 3\times\text{integer} + 3 + 1 = 3\times(\text{integer} + 1) + 1.$$ We are done.

Comment: This makes sense to me and I am able to finish problem thank you

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = 3k+r, r = 0, 1, 2$ by the division algorithm. Squaring $x$, we find $x^2 = 9k^2+6kr+r^2$, or $x^2 = (9k+6r)k+r^2$.

Since $9k+6r$ is divisible by 3 for all integers $k, r$, then we may re-write this as $x^2 = 3k_1 + r^2$.

Using the division algorithm again, we see that $x^2 = 3k_1+r_1, r_1 = 0, 1, 2$. If $r_1 = 2$, then $r = \pm \sqrt{2}$, which is not an integer. Therefore, only $r=0$ and $r=1$ are acceptable.

Comment: **x^2 =9k^2+12*q+4** when r=2 .Then again when we try to express square of a number in **3q+r** form we get **x1=3*q1 +4** now as we know **0<=r<b** but here we have 4 which is greater than 3 hence its not correct and cannot accept **2** while expressing squares in form of **3q+1**. @Emily am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Below I give an analogous proof for divisor $5$ (vs. $3),$ exploiting reflection symmetry.

**Lemma** $\ $ Every integer $\rm\:n\:$ has form $\rm\: n = 5\,k \pm r,\:$ for $\rm\:r\in\{0,1,2\},\ k\in\Bbb Z.$

**Proof** $\ $ By the Division algorithm

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} n &=&\:\rm 5\,q + \color{#c00}r\ \ \ for\ \ some\ \ q,r\in\Bbb Z,\:\ r\in [0,4] \\
                        &=&\:\rm 5\,(q\!+\!1)-(\color{#0a0}{5\!-\!r})
\end{eqnarray}$$

Since $\rm\:\color{#0a0}{5\!-\!r}+\color{#c00}r = 5,\,$ one summand is $\le 2,\,$ so lies in $\{0,1,2\},\,$ yielding the result.

**Theorem** $\ $ The square of an integer $\rm\,n\,$ has form $\rm\, n^2 = \,5\,k + r\,$ for $\rm\:r\in \{0,1,4\}.$

**Proof** $\ $ By  Lemma $\rm\ n^2 = (5k\pm r)^2 = 5\,(5k^2\!\pm 2kr)+r^2\,$ for $\rm\:r\in \{0,1,2\},\,$ so $\rm\: r^2\in\{0,1,4\}.$

**Remark** $\ $ Your divisor of $\,3\,$ is analogous, with $\rm\:r\in \{0,1\}\,$ so $\rm\:r^2\in \{0,1\}.\,$ The same method generalizes for any divisor $\rm\:m,\,$ yielding that $\rm\:n^2 = m\,k + r^2,\,$ for $\rm\:r\in\{0,1,\ldots,\lfloor m/2\rfloor\}.$
The reason we need only square half the remainders is because we have exploited reflection symmetry (negation) to note that remainders $\rm > n$ can be transformed to negatives of remainders $\rm < n,\,$ e.g. $\rm\: 13 = 5\cdot 2 +\color{#0A0} 3 = 5\cdot 3 \color{#C00}{- 2},\,$ i.e. remainder $\rm\:\color{#0A0}3\leadsto\,\color{#C00}{-2},\,$ i.e. $\rm\:3 \equiv -2\pmod 5.\:$ This amounts to using a system of *balanced* (or *signed*) remainders $\rm\, 0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots,\pm n\ $ vs. $\rm\ 0,1,2,\ldots,2n[-1].\:$ Often this optimization halves work for problems  independent of the sign of the remainder.

All of this is much clearer when expressed in terms of [congruences (modular arithmetic),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) e.g. the key inference above  $\rm\:n\equiv r\:\Rightarrow\:n^2\equiv r^2\pmod m\:$  is a special case of the ubiquitous

[**Congruence Product Rule**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\rm\ \ A\equiv a,\ B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ AB\equiv ab\ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\:\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\:\ \Rightarrow\:\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a)\ B + a\ (B\!-\!b)\ =\ AB - ab $

For an introduction to congruences see any decent  textbook on elementary number theory.