# The square of every integer is of the form either $3k+1$ or $3k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I prove that square of every integer is of the form either $3k+1$ or $3k$,  but not $3k+2$?

#### My approach

I considered first, the integer $n$ to be even and then  $n= 2m$;  and if $n$ is odd then $n=2m+1$ but this step takes me to nowhere. I get usually stuck in these kind of questions. and this time I seriously need help . So, please post answer in detail and also mention how and why you arrived at that particular step.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not see you take the square of the integers you made.

Comment: Take $n=3k$ or $n=3k\pm 1$

Comment: Nearly the same: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172535/use-the-division-algorithm-to-show-the-square-of-any-integer-is-in-the-form-3k

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**: Instead of looking at $n = 2m$ or $n = 2m+1$, look at $n = 3m$ or $n = 3m \pm 1$.

Comment: Really a simple problem but I failed to find the hint , that is in the problem itself. Thanks... understood the approach.

Answer (score 2):

So you mean, that the quadratic residue $x^2 \neq 2 \bmod 3$:
$$
(3m\pm 1)^2=9m^2\pm6m+1=3m'+1 =1 \bmod 3 \neq 2 \bmod 3
$$
$(3m)^2$ is obvious...

Answer (score 0):

Assume $n=3q+r$, $r={0,1,2}$ as per Euclid's lemma. Then $n^2=(3q+r)^2$ $$n^2=(3q)^2+ 2.3q.r +r^2$$ $$n^2=3(3q^2)+3.(2q.r)+r^2$$ $$n^2=3(3q^2+2qr)+r^2$$ $$n^2=3m+r^2,m \in Z$$. If $r=0$ then $n^2=3m+0$, If $r=1$ then $n^2=3m+1$ and if $r=2$ then $n^2=3m+2^2$ i.e., $n^2=3m+3+1$. Therefore $n^2=3m+1$ and never $n^2=3n+2$. Q.E.D.